# Displaying the date pattern string in Rails i18n localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'd like to get the template string of the localized date format in Rails. What I'm going for:

```
date_in_us = get_date_string(:en) # 'mm/dd/yyyy'
date_in_gb = get_date_string(:en-gb) # 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

So to be clear I'm not trying to localize a real date, I'm trying to get the date format string so I could display it as a placeholder in a text field.

Everything I've searched for on the internet keeps bringing me back to actually localizing a date. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work because that's not how the format is specified. For English, [this](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/a21e6f276958ccd46535c3a7868c63426f77f4ff/rails/locale/en.yml#L41-L44) is how the date formats are specified:

```
formats:
  default: "%Y-%m-%d"
  long: "%B %d, %Y"
  short: "%b %d"
```

[Here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) are the docs for these percent placeholders in case you're curious.

To solve your problem, I'd create a date, localize it, and replace the parts:

```
date = Date.new(2000, 12, 31)
I18n.l(date).sub('2000', 'yyyy').sub('12', 'mm').sub('31', 'dd')
# => "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Note that this might not work if the locale uses a 2 digit year format. Let's try it for some locales (using the default from rails-i18n):

```
def get_date_string(locale = I18n.current)
  date = Date.new(2000, 12, 31)
  I18n.l(date, locale: locale)
    .sub('2000', 'yyyy')
    .sub('12', 'mm')
    .sub('31', 'dd')
end

formats = %i[en en-US en-GB es de fr pt].map do |locale|
  [locale, get_date_string(locale)]
end.to_h
```

`formats` will be:

```
{
  :en=>"yyyy-mm-dd",
  :"en-US"=>"mm-dd-yyyy",
  :"en-GB"=>"dd-mm-yyyy",
  :es=>"dd/mm/yyyy",
  :de=>"dd.mm.yyyy",
  :fr=>"dd/mm/yyyy",
  :pt=>"dd/mm/yyyy"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default all translations should be placed inside the config/locales directory, divided into files.

Below is a sample `en.yml` with date patterns.

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

So, all of the following equivalent lookups will return the :short date format "%b %d":

```
I18n.t 'date.formats.short'
I18n.t 'formats.short', scope: :date
I18n.t :short, scope: 'date.formats'
I18n.t :short, scope: [:date, :formats]
```

Please check this [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/i18n.html) on how to i18n localization works in Ruby on Rails

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, please read the OP more carefully.